# jquery .mousemove fires every time a slide changes

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I have a slide animation page. After I first move the mouse on this page, the mousemove event fires every time the slide function runs even though there isn't anything in the slide function that refers to the  mouse. If I run the slide just once, and not in a loop, it works correctly. Or, if I run the slide in a loop but don't touch the mouse at all, the slide loop doesn't incorrectly fire any mousemove events either. The problem is only when the slide is auto-looping and I've moved the mouse once.

Slide function like this runs on a loop:

```
function slide(id) {
    $(“.thumb”).addClass(“inactive”);
    $(".thumb:nth-of-type("+(id+1)+")").addClass("active");

    $(“.thumb-container”).animate({ marginLeft: '-'+nextPos+'px' }, {
        duration: 500, 
        easing: "easeOutCubic", 
        complete: function() {
            console.log(“anim done”);
        }
    });
}


setInterval(function() { slide(id++); }, 200);
```

and then, outside of the function:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    console.log("mouse moving");    
});
```

UPDATE: Strange, this issue is resolved when I comment out the following from the slide function:

```
$(".thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type("+(lastSlide+1)+")").removeClass("active-thumb");
$(".thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type("+(lastSlide+1)+") .inactive-overlay").fadeIn(300);
$(".thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type("+(id+1)+")").addClass("active-thumb");
$(".thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type("+(id+1)+") .inactive-overlay").fadeOut(300);
```

UPDATE: SOLVED!
It was because class .active-thumb was using:

```
cursor: default;
```

Comment: Is something triggering your setInterval, or are you running that on page load. What does it have to do with mousemove?

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: That's what baffles me. My setInterval doesn't have anything to do with the mousemove.

Comment: Are you saying your slide function when ran on an interval is triggering mousemove events? The only way a mousemove event would be triggered with the given code is when... you move... the mouse.

Comment: Here's a fiddle, it appears to be working as it should.. http://jsfiddle.net/X22Xm/

Comment: I've updated my original post to show which code was causing the issue. Strange!